# How can I change screen using bottom sheet in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have made a simple app in kivymd. But I can not change screen on click on button inside kivymd. Everything works great. But when I click on button then it popup toast also but screen is not changing. What will be changes or better implementation for this?

**app.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from main_screen_str import helper_string
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDGridBottomSheet

Window.size = (300, 500)


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass


class AboutScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name="settings_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(AboutScreen(name="about_screen"))

        self.main_str = Builder.load_string(helper_string)

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        screen.add_widget(self.main_str)
        return screen

    def callback_for_menu_items(self, *args):
        if args[0] == 'Home':
            toast(args[0])
            self.sm.current = "main_screen"

        if args[0] == 'Settings':
            toast(args[0])
            self.sm.current = "settings_screen"

        if args[0] == 'About':
            toast(args[0])
            self.sm.current = "about_screen"

    def show_example_grid_bottom_sheet(self):
        self.bottom_sheet_menu = MDGridBottomSheet()

        data = {
            "Home": "home",
            "Settings": "settings",
            "About": "information-outline",
        }
        for item in data.items():
            self.bottom_sheet_menu.add_item(
                item[0],
                lambda x, y=item[0]: self.callback_for_menu_items(y),
                icon_src=item[1],
            )
        self.bottom_sheet_menu.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

This builder string to create screen.
Are there any better solution for this?

**builder string**

```
helper_string = """
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    SettingsScreen:
    AboutScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main_screen'

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "menu"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: 1,0,0,1
        on_press: app.show_example_grid_bottom_sheet()
  
<SettingsScreen>:
    name: 'settings_screen'
    
<AboutScreen>:
    name: 'about_screen'      
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__()` method of the `App`, you are building `self.sm` with the lines:

```
    self.sm = ScreenManager()
    self.sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_screen"))
    self.sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name="settings_screen"))
    self.sm.add_widget(AboutScreen(name="about_screen"))
```

But `self.sm` is not used as part of your GUI. So your changes to `self.sm` has no effect on your GUI. The line following that:

```
self.main_str = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
```

basically does exactly the same thing as the previous lines.

Then in your `build()` method, you are creating a new `Screen` and adding the `self.main_str` as a child of that `Screen`.

While you can have a `ScreenManager` as a child of a `Screen`, in your posted example that does not seem to serve any purpose.

Here is a modified version of part of the `MainApp` that I think will do what you want:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #     super().__init__(**kwargs)
    #     self.sm = ScreenManager()
    #     self.sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_screen"))
    #     self.sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name="settings_screen"))
    #     self.sm.add_widget(AboutScreen(name="about_screen"))
    #
    #     self.main_str = Builder.load_string(helper_string)

    def build(self):
        self.sm = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return self.sm
        # screen = Screen()
        # screen.add_widget(self.main_str)
        # return screen
```

The above code greatly simplifies the `build()` method, eliminates the `__init__()` method, and now `self.sm` is actually part of the GUI.

Note that when you load a `kv` string that has a root node with `Builder.load_string()`, that root node is created and returned. The lines in your `kv` string:

```
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    SettingsScreen:
    AboutScreen:
```

result in a `ScreenManager` instance being created along with the three children listed for it, so the code in your `__init__()` method was duplicating that.